# Powershell SetAttribute adding Carriage return Line Feed characters

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-ise

I have an xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add value="020_8" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to modify the "value" attribute. Here is the powershell script:

```
param($configfilepath, $buildrev)
[string]$foldername = Out-String -InputObject $buildrev
$error.clear()
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load($configfilepath)
$xml.configuration.appSettings.add.SetAttribute('value',$foldername)
$xml.Save($configfilepath)
```

This does modify the xml attribute to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add value="025&#xD;&#xA;" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The value that I wanted was 025 but it also added

> `"&#xD;&#xA;"`

which is not what I want. How can I fix it?

Comment: `Out-String` adds a trailing newline. Why are you using that. Why not simply set `$buildrev` as new value for the attribute?

Comment: How can I do this? Should I get the attribute node using xpath?

Comment: Thanks it does not add those characters but leads into another issue. If I pass 025 from command line, it ignores 0 and just updates the attribute value to 25. If I pass 025_1, it then takes 025_1

Comment: Basically, if the parameter can be converted to int, it converts it, otherwise treats it as string. (because of _ in 025_1)

Comment: Or `$foldername = "$buildrev"` to use the string representation. (Note that depending on the `$buildrev` type (you might want to add that `$buildrev.GetType()` to the question), you might get different result on `"$buildrev"` or `$buildrev.ToString()` but in the end you could also consider: `(Out-String -InputObject $buildrev).Trim()` to trim any white spaces (including `CR` and `LF`)

Comment: I would change the parameter declaraction to `[string]$buildrev` and call using quotes around the param `"025"`